# Store html form data into php file

Tags: php, html

I am making a blog without using a database. So I have a add entry form which when submitted should be processed by a php file that creates files for the entries. My question is how do i store multiple files?? 
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of files would you like to be exported?

Comment: @fiskerXO He wants to store in plain text files

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

### Creates the file

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
```

### Write to a file

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = 'This is the data';
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

Further information:[more file handling in PHP](http://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username']; //this allows the user to return to blog and edit      before submitting
$filename = $username . "/entry.txt";

$handle = fopen($filename, "a+");
$entrydata = fread($handle, filesize($filename)); //opens file for reading, and reads the file for any text that may already exist
fclose($handle); //close the handle

if (!empty($_POST['posted'])){ //maybe add this as a hidden field in your form to verify     if the form was actually posted

  $entry = $_POST['entry']; //saves text that has been entered in the entry form
  $handle = fopen($filename, "w+");

  if (flock($handle, LOCK_EX)){  //an exclusive lock to file
   if (fwrite($handle, $entry) == FALSE){
    echo "Cannot write to file";
   }
 flock ($handle, LOCK_UN); //release the lock
 }
}
else{
//some code
}
```

Comment: What if i wanted to add multiple entries to different files?